# Referring created users to 'admins' that created them

Tags: users

I know user can be given a permission to create other users. However, it doesn't seem that user table has any created_by field to store the ID of the creator. Does it?

Is there a way not only to create a field like that (could do it through profiles management) but also to actually put creators ID in it with just using drupal base config or some module?

I simply need to be able to list users created by a particular 'admin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field (e.g. created_by) to the user profile by going to /admin/config/people/accounts/fields.

Then implement [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) to populate the field whenever a new user is added.

hook_user_insert is called after "*A user account was created.*" 
So both $edit->uid and $account->uid have the user id present.

If you changed any values in either of these objects you would need to call user_save in order to save your changes.

An alternative to avoid calling user_save again, just after the initial user object has been saved would be to use [hook_user_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) that is called when *"A user account is about to be created or updated"*

The description of hook_user_presave goes on to say:

*This hook is primarily intended for modules that want to store properties in the serialized {users}.data column, which is automatically loaded whenever a user account object is loaded, modules may add to $edit['data'] in order to have their data serialized on save.*

So another option here would be instead of creating a new field (with a new table), this information could just be stored as a serialized array in the data column of the user table.

This would mean it would be slower to search for users created by a certain admin, but would would have less storage overheads.

Comment: ok, as far as I can see a custom field created this way gets a new table created in the db - field_data_xxx (where xxx is the field name). In this particular scenario it requires the entity ID, which would be the ID of the user that was just created. How can I call the ID of newly created user in this hook?

Comment: I've updated by answer...

Comment: Thanks. That worked nicely. Is there a way however to allow some admin users to create other users but limit their access to people related admin settings? It seems there's only one option under permissions - Administer users - which seems to dictate either full package (create all different profile2 users, access admin people list view etc) or nothing

Comment: Yes - however I think that question deserves a whole new thread as opposed to trying to answer it in a comment...